# A quick question about a logical negation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I just want to make sure I'm negating the following logical statement correctly (for a contradiction proof):

For every set $A$, there exists a well ordered set $V$ such that there exists no surjection $\pi: A \rightarrow V$.

I'm negating this as:

For every set $A$, there exists a well ordered set $V$ such that there exists a surjection $\pi: A \rightarrow V$.

Is this a correct negation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You've only negated one part of the statement. Negating each part:

*There exists* a set $A$ so that *for all* well-ordered sets $V$ *there exists* a surjection $\pi:A\to V$.

I think I've negated what you're actually going for here.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually exactly what I was hoping it would be.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a correct negation. [Quantifiers switch when you negate.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Negation) As such, the "for every" becomes a "there exists...such that", the "there exists" becomes a "for every", and "such that" is deleted for grammar reasons.